# Exception when make object from Skype in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, skype

I applied code in this Article in windows 8 x64:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37909/Make-your-Skype-Bot-in-NET?fid=1543353&fr=1#xx4637154xx

When I run this code show me COMException was unhandled

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {830690FC-BF2F-47A6-AC2D-330BCB402664} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154.

the Exception show me in line code":

```
skype = new Skype();
```

Comment: Is the SkypeCOM dll registered? Also do you have the correct version of Skype installed. I remember it removed the SkypeCOM functionality, don't know if it is back again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS -> project properties -> in the Build tab -> platform target =X86

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered the DLL? Take a look at this Blog http://donchevp.blogspot.in/2008/08/skype4com-lib-how-to-register-skype.html

From above blog:

In the command prompt type : regsvr32 Skype4COM.dll or "regsvr32 C:\Program Files\Common Files\Skype\Skype4COM.dll"